# インストールとインポートの名前がことなるのはなぜか？

Tags: python, linux

PILについてです。

pipを使いインストールするときは

sudo pip install pillow

しかし、インポートをするときは
import PIL

なぜ、pillowとPIL名前が異なるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 4):

[`Pillow`](http://python-pillow.org/)は[`PIL`](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/)というライブラリの[フォーク](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow)ですので、この場合は`Pillow`の`import`は元のライブラリの`import`と同じなんです。言い換えると、`Pillow`は`PIL`の置き換えて使用することができるライブラリなんですから、`Pillow`の`import`は`PIL`の`import`と同じです。

また、`PIL`自体は[`setuptools`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools)とは、もともと[互換性のないもの](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/image-sig/2010-August/006480.html)ですし、バグ・問題を適切に修正するために、あるデベロッパーには`PIL`の開発のスケジュールは[遅すぎたよう](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.1.x/about.html#why-a-fork)ですので、`PIL`はとうとうフォークされたようです。